# Is Sodium for Java a good fit for using it with Scala+ScalaFX?

Tags: scala, javafx, reactive-programming, scalafx

After watching [this](http://youtu.be/gaG3tIb3Lbk) talk I decided to try to make a Scala/ScalaFX app in a reactive style. Naturally, after this talk, I am thinking about using the Java implementation of the Sodium [library](http://blog.reactiveprogramming.org) for this task. I am unsure, however, how compatible it is with Scala?

Would Sodium Java be a good way to build a reactive ScalaFX app or should I look for a more suitable framework for this task ?

Here is a more specific question to people who already tried this combination:

What difficulties ( if any ) did arise when combining Sodium Java with Scala/ScalaFX ?

Comment: Note that JavaFx(and thus ScalaFx) supports [bind expressions](https://code.google.com/p/scalafx/#Natural_Language_Bind_Expressions). Could this be considered _reactive_? [The property binding](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm) ensures that the resulting expression is automatically reevaluated once the source arguments change.